# Identify the physical keyboard button pressed in Javascript, irrespective of the current locale?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, dom-events, keyboard-events

I'd like to setup event handlers based on what key is pressed on the Keyboard. This is reasonable simple for commonly occurring keyboard letters like (0-9,A-Z, etc), as their position on the keyboard is almost the same on all keyboards and the key codes can be used to identify the key pressed. ( using `event.which()` )

However, I'd like to setup handlers in such a way that I can identity keys based on their position on keyboard. For example US (:/;) is at the same physical location at Swedish (Ö/ö), but I'd like to able to setup a unique handler for that position on the keyboard.

In Eng, pressing ';' `event.which()` returns 59
In Swe, pressing 'ö' `event.which()` returns 246
and they both belong to the same physical location on the keyboard.
I'm looking for a solution where this one physical location has a unique id.

Is this even possible at all (without using something that would detect the current locale and then map the keys to target locale with some internal id etc..).

I believe there are several complex ways to solve this, but I'm interested in the simplest way to solve this. Any pre-written libraries happily accepted.

Comment: event.which() as I've mentioned above, which I believe wraps around event.keyCode() and event.charCode(), any other properties/methods that could be useful ?

Comment: There are three separate events: `keydown`, `keypress` and `keyup`. `keydown` and `keyup` work very similarly and report information about physical keys. `keypress` is concerned with the character typed. So, you can get different information from each. The definitive resource for JavaScript key events is http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to map the locations depending on the keycodes. For example, you could write such that keycode for ; and o map to the keycode for ; . Similarly u'd need a list of all the keycodes that resolve around that location..

Sorry, but there's no easy way.

Comment: well, that really sucks ! but I was hoping if a library existed to attack this problem.